# Semaphores makeWater() synchronization

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

[image: MakeWater() synchronization pseudocode]

This program claims to solve makeWater() synchronization problem. However, I could not understand how. I am new in semaphores. I would appriciate if you can help me to understand this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you need to make H2O (2Hs and one O) combinations out of number of simultaneously running H-threads and O-threads.

The thing is one 'O' needs two 'H' s. And no sharings between two different water molecules.

So assume number of O and H threads start their processes.

- No O thread can go beyond `P(o_wait)` because o-wait is locked, and should wait.
- One random lucky H thread(say H*-1) can go pass `P(mutex)`(now mutex = 0 and  count = 1)  and and will go inside `if(count%2 == 1)`, then up-count 'mutex' (now mutex = 1) and block in `P(h_wait)`. (This count actually refers to H count)
- Because 'mutex' was up-counted another random H-thread(H*-2) will start to go pass `P(mutex)` (Now mutex = 0 and count =2). But now the count is even -> hence it goes inside `else`. Then it will `V(o_wait)`(now o_wait = 1) and stuck in `P(h_wait)`.
- Now H*-1 is still at the previous position inside `if` block. But because o_wait is up-counted to 1, a lucky O thread(O*) can continue its process. It will do two `V(h_wait)` s (Now o_wait = 0, h_wait = 2), so that 2 previous H threads can continue(No any other, now h_wait = 0). So all 3 (2 Hs and O) can finish its process, while H*-2 is up-counting the 'mutex' (now mutex = 1).
- Now the final values of global variables after completion one molecule, mutex = 1, h_wait = 0 and o_wait = 0, so exactly the initial status. Now the previous process will happen again and again, hence H2O molecules will be created.

I think you get clear with it. Please raise questions if any. :))

Comment: It is a great explanation =) I've understood very well! Thanks a lot Supun @Supun Wijerathne

Comment: @Blu always nice to see (Y) :))